# Using HTTP proxy in PHP

Tags: php, proxy

May you give me an example for using an HTTP proxy in PHP?

Comment: Doing what? Using which functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use PHP to make an HTTP request via a proxy, you can use the [*proxy* context option](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Example:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'proxy'  => 'tcp://proxy.example.com:5100',
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/somefile.html', false, $context);
```